# pandas pd.read_excel puts all into one column

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I would need some help/ideas again.

I have been working on a pandas jupyter notebook for some data wrangling with a file I get from our customer. Unfortunately I cannot disclose it.

Previous version I could read in using pd.read_excel(), however, for the latest one, everything is put under just ONE column, the first one. data is in rows, that is ok, however, each row content is in just the first column.

df=pd.read_excel('./Files/import/ET5X report 03-01-2021.xlsx', header=0, usecols="A:BF")

I even tried to explicitly use "usecols" command, but no change.

Any ideas, what I could check? .csv would be an alternative, but then I have some trouble with the format of some of the cells.

Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Perhaps doing df=df.T could help. This transposes the dataframe and seems to me like this is what you wanted at the end

Comment: You can try different engines when reading file, for example `engine='openpyxl'`.